# How to show information when I will come in a range of created location

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

Sorry if my question could be "silly" but I am new Android programmer.
I've wrote the app based on that example:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html
Everything works fine. It show my current location and I receive location updates. 
I've added a specific location.
When I come in a range of that location only show the text "ERROR".
What I did wrong?

```
public void firstLocation (View v) {
      final Location loc = new Location ("");
      loc.setLatitude(47.2175723);
      loc.setLongitude(17.1427797);
      loc.setAccuracy(10);

      if (mLocationClient.getLastLocation() == loc) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "SOME INFORMATION",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
       else
          Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
```

Comment: Firstly, to compare two object you should use `equals`, not `==`.

Comment: Thanks.I will try equals method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Proximity Alerts.
Proximity Alert gives you notification (triggers piece of code) when you come in or goes out from particular location range.

http://androidmyway.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/proximity-alert-in-android/#more-143
or
http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2012/10/proximity-alerts.html

can help you to start.

Comment: It could be a good solution but I read that LocationClient is more efficent and have greater accuracy than LocationManager.